# Best practice for saving a dynamic HTML form

Tags: forms, xhtml

I'm looking for the best practice for saving a dynamic HTML form.  The fields of the form are added the the page by AJAX.  Each field is similar to:

```
<input type="text" name="field_12" />
```

Where, in this case, "12" is the primary key for the field in the database.

I plan to send these fields via POST back to the server for saving.  When it's time to save, I do not know the `name` attributes that will be coming over.

I can think of two ways to do this.

1. Have a hidden item with a list of field ids.  I can then parse it before doing the inserts.
   `<input type="hidden" name="fieldIds" value="1,2,12,14" />`
2. Query the database for the expected field ids, then do the inserts based on that.

I can see advantages and disadvantages of both scenarios.  What is the best practice in this situation?

I'm using classic ASP on an IIS server, although, I don't think that's a factor here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make input fields like

```
<input type="hidden" name="field[]" value="12" />
<input type="hidden" name="field[]" value="13" />
<input type="hidden" name="field[]" value="14" />
...
```

it will become array on server side

and loop it through, then insert

Comment: If the `value` is set to the field ID, I'm not sure how the user will be able to fill out those fields without losing what is in the `value`.  Are these supposed to be `hidden`, and used alongside `text` ones?

Comment: @dangowans Sorry, I have edited my solution. It should be hidden and will be added dynamically